# Soap ui maven plugin Java 17

Tags: testing, soapui, java-17

After migration to Java 17 I faced with a next issue

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean cannot access class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.ssl to unnamed module @a0bdbe2
```

My question is, How to apply  *--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED*  args for run soapUI test command. Or do we have some another approach to execute soapUI test on JDK17

Comment: Should be `--add-opens java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: Yes, you are right but how to pass this, it is a main question

Comment: Usually on the command line. No idea what executes the soapUI test command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters can be passed vis MAVEN_OPTS

Answer (score 1):

Added it to the SoapUI-5.6.0/bin/SoapUI-5.6.0.sh java execution line

```
$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX exec "$app_java_home/bin/java" "-splash:$app_home/.install4j/s_12opuop.png" **--add-opens java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED** -Dinstall4j.jvmDir="$app_java_home" -Dexe4j.moduleName="$prg_dir/$progname" "-Dinstall4j.launcherId=64" "-Dinstall4j.swt=false" "$vmov_1" "$vmov_2" "$vmov_3" "$vmov_4" "$vmov_5" $INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS -classpath "$local_classpath" com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher launch a0622774 "$prg_dir/error.log" 0 com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI  "$@"
```